# Close wxDialog in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

[image]

As seen in the picture above..

I created a wxDialog in wxWidgets. The user can click Yes or No. Upon clicking either button a standard dialog is opened giving a simple message (either Overwrite Success, or Overwrite Cancel)

Upon the click of either Yes or No, I want the primary dialog (the larger one) to close

```
void OverwriteDLG::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
     wxMessageBox ("Overwrite Complete","CopyMeister v1.0",wxOK);
}
```

The above code is the event handler of the 'Yes' button. I tried the destroy function and I tried the close function. I searched the internet thoroughly but I couldn't find much help. Sometimes the program works syntactically, but the dialog never closes.

The dialog is called OverwriteDLG

Answer (score 3):

> I searched the internet thoroughly but I couldn't find much help.

The page below describes the *wxDialog* class.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_dialog.html

From my reading of that page, **if** the dialog was create as **modal**, then the **EndModal** function can be used to close the dialog, returning the user action via the return code.

Comment: This means I need a return code which is to be retrieved from the ShowModal() function.

The ShowModal function for this dialog is called in a method in another class. I am saving it's value in a global long integer. But how can I use this variable in the end modal method if it's from a different class. 

I know this might be a silly question but I'm still very new to C++ Programming and wxwidgets.

Comment: You call ShowModal to display the dialog and that call will not return until you have call EndModal. You can pass what every value you want to EndModal and the value you do pass in will be returned by ShowModal.

Answer (score -1):

for close use: this->Close(true);

Comment: This is wrong for a modal dialog, it needs to be closed using `EndModal()` as explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: Err, no, it isn't? The question is about how to close the dialog.